# jQuery function fades in multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(".home").hover(
    function () {
        $(".arrow-down").show();
        if ($(window).width() < 900) {
            $(".arrow-down").css("left", "70px"); 
            $(".titleHome").fadeIn(); 
        }
        else {   
            $(".arrow-down").css("left", "100px");
        }
    },
    function () {
         $(".arrow-down").hide();
         $(".titleHome").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

and html

```
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="arrows">
            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="home">Home</button>
            <button class="about">About</button>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="titleHome">
        <p1>Home</p1>
        <div id="bubble"></div>
        <div id="tri"></div>
    </div>
```

As the window is resized to dimensions under 900px, I move `arrow-down` to the left by 70px, and I am making `.titleHome` fade in to display. It all works fine but for one trivial thing that I can't figure out. If I hold the cursor over `.home`, then `.titleHome` will fade in, the fade out, then fade in...All I want is for it to fade in on hover-in, and fade-out on hover-out, but for some reason `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are called twice. Any suggestions as to why it does this?

Comment: can we see your html?

Comment: @Bindrid I posted it

Comment: can u add JSFiddel ...??

Comment: @AminKodaganur how about I give you the link to my site?

Comment: hahah ur funny .... i have added jsfiddel can u at least add css in it here is link https://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/yfw8s4g1/

Comment: @AminKodaganur I didn't add all the css but this should be enough. Notice how when you hover over home button that the other little home appears, disappears and reappears https://jsfiddle.net/yfw8s4g1/1/

Comment: @AminKodaganur hold on use this one https://jsfiddle.net/yfw8s4g1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experience this. Removing css top (and left too) fixes this.

```js
$(".home").hover(
  function() {
    $(".arrow-down").show();
    if ($(window).width() < 900) {
      $(".arrow-down").css("left", "70px");
      $(".titleHome").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(".arrow-down").css("left", "100px");
    }
  },
  function() {
    $(".arrow-down").hide();
    $(".titleHome").fadeOut();
  }
);
```

```css
.home {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("tricolour-queens-university-oneclass.png");
  background-size: 33px 23px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 3px;
}

.about {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
  left: 65px;
  top: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.titleHome {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="arrows">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="home">Home</button>
    <button class="about">About</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="titleHome">
  <p1>Home</p1>
  <div id="bubble"></div>
  <div id="tri"></div>
</div>
```

But I can't explain this. Open for someone to explain.